# When dynamic framework loaded to memory

Tags: ios, swift

I created a new target of type "Cocoa Touch Framework"
The questions are:
- When does this framework loaded to memory? at launch time or on runtime (when using it)
- is there a way to make it loaded on runtime to improve launch time?

Comment: This WWDC presentation might be of use to you. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/413/